# How do Payment Channel Networks such as Raiden actually increase blockchain scalability?

Tags: scalability, off-chain, state-channels, raiden, l2

**Question** : If a payment channel network that routes multi-hop payments uses HTLC's (hash time locked contracts) which must first lock up funds on-chain and also be redeemed on-chain then how are they actually increasing scalability.

**My current understanding:** To me it seems as though it should actually lead to more on-chain transactions/computation. This is because instead of just one transfer function call from sender to receiver for a regular transaction, in a multi-hop payment there must be an on-chain HTLC creation and redemption contract call for every intermediary. Otherwise how would claimants obtain the locked tokens before the time lock expiry? I'm clearly missing something I just can't seem to find the answer anywhere online. Thanks in advance for any help.